Port large VS C++ solution to linux
I have a task to port a pretty large windows C++ program to linux. The Visual Studio solution (.sln) contains 50+ projects with ~4K source files so I'd like to automate it as much as possible. Each project file (.vcxproj) contains only the file list and a bunch of included custom .props with the actual configuration for the project. On the positive side the program has no UI and I have cleaned up windows dependencies so that it uses only standard library + boost and can be compiled with clang. What would be a reasonable approach to this task?
So far I have tried the cmake-converter which failed on resolving the paths to the included .props files and generated nothing. The second attempt was to use msbuild in linux, but it seems to work only for .net languages there as all cpp specific props are missing.

How complicated are your .props files? How many .props file do you have?

Nothing beats reading the project files/props, understanding what they do, and replicating that (probably in CMake).

@Jarod42:  there are around 30 relevant .props

Well use whatever cmake-converter did right and manually fix the rest? You might even find some unecessary dependencies to cleanup. At least this is not a repeating job

@Jarod42: now I think the complex .props are not really relevant for my use case. Those complicated ones are for building the whole application (with UI, 300+ projects) - my solution is a cut out "core". Relevant is a large common props with compiler and linker settings and the rest can be reduced to additional include and lib directories

@Pepijn Kramer: cmake-converter was able to do literally nothing: not a single line

Aw that's unfortunate

Then doing manually CMake (with globing) seems feasible, or create your own simplified script for the conversion.

I'm a little bit surprised that it is such an uncommon use case that practically no tooling exists. Ok, manual work with some simple helper script it is then. Thank you all for the comments.
